# Save each dataframe in a list as a CSV, and make the filename the same as the df name - R; lapply

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of dataframes. I'd like to save each dataframe as a separate CSV file and make the filename the same as the name of the dataframe.

```
df <- list(mtcars, iris, ToothGrowth) df <- setNames(df, c("mtcars",
"iris", "ToothGrowth"))

lapply(df, function(a) write.csv(a, file = paste0("C:/home/",
unlist(lapply(names(df)), function (b) b)), ".csv"), row.names = FALSE))
```

Gives the error:

> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :    invalid
>   'description' argument In addition: Warning message: In if (file ==
>   "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
>
> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a",
>   "w")) :    invalid 'description' argument

I'm pretty certain the issue is in the second `lapply` command, but I can't seem to figure out how to "automatically" assign the file names based on `df` name. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to iterate both names and data.frames, you are better off using `mapply` to walk both lists at the same time

```
mapply(function(dname, data) 
   write.csv(data, file = paste0("C:/home/", dname, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE), 
   names(df), df)
```

when iterating a list via `lapply()` the current value name is not available. An altertative using `lapply` is to iterate the names, not the values

```
lapply(names(df), function(dname) 
   write.csv(df[[dname]], file = paste0("C:/home/", dname, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE))
```

Comment: Is there a way to alter this code if there's an extra level of nested lists? ie: now `df` is contained in a `masterlist`? Or do I need a lapply/mapply combination?

Comment: I've posted this as a new question, in case you have the time/interest to tackle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52819642/saving-deeply-nested-files-to-specific-directories-with-specific-filenames

Answer (score 2):

`purrr` has functions that start with `i` that make indexed mapping easy. Since you don't need to return anything, `iwalk` will work well. Given a named list, `iwalk` then applies a function with the list item and list item's name as arguments, so you don't need any extra steps to extract names like with the base `apply` functions. My file paths are different only because I'm on a Mac--feel free to ignore that.

```r
df <- list(mtcars, iris, ToothGrowth) 
df <- setNames(df, c("mtcars", "iris", "ToothGrowth"))

purrr::iwalk(df, function(dat, name) write.csv(dat, file = paste0("./", name, ".csv")))
```

Comment: How would I modify this for a more nested list? ie, `df` and its elements are now contained in a new list, `masterlist`?

Comment: That seems like a different question. You can probably find a post that deals with a situation like that, or put up a new one

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure whether to post a new question, but I'll take you're advice :)

Comment: In case the solution interests you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52819642/saving-deeply-nested-files-to-specific-directories-with-specific-filenames