# Saving deeply nested files to specific directories with specific filenames

Tags: r, lapply, purrr, mapply

Given a 3 level nested list:

```
mylist <- list("1000"=list("cars"=list("fast"=mtcars[1:10,], "slow"=mtcars[11:15,]), "flower"=iris), "2000"=list("tooth"=ToothGrowth, "air"=airquality, "cars"=list("cruiser"=mtcars[5:12,], "fast"=mtcars[1:3,], "mild"=mtcars[9:18,])))
```

[image: visual nested list example]

(ie: `mylist$1000$cars$fast`, where `fast` is a dataframe, and `cars` and `1000` are nested lists in `mylist`)

I'd like to save each innermost dataframe, (ie: `fast`) as a .csv with the df name as it's file name, ie: `fast.csv`, **and** I want the file to be saved in a directory that is named after the second level of list, ie: `~/1000/fast.csv`.

Each directory already exists, so I do not need to create a new `1000` and `2000` directory.

My instinct is to do a nested `lapply` or `lapply`/`mapply` combination...but keeping track of the different levels and their names is challenging me.  I know that `purrr` has the `iwalk` function, but I'm not sure how to use it within deeply nested list.

My current attempt fails.

```
lapply(mylist, function(d){
  lapply(names(mylist), function(id){
    lapply(names(d$cars), function(s){
    lapply(d$cars, function(a){
        write.csv(a, paste0(outdir, id, "/", s, ".csv"))})})})})
```

The output results in a single file being saved under multiple names into all the directories.  ie: `~/1000/cruiser.csv`, `~/1000/fast.csv`, `~/1000/mild.csv`, `~/2000/cruiser.csv`, `~/2000/fast.csv`, `~/2000/mild.csv` ... where all the files are actually just a csv of `mylist$2000$cars$mild`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the sub-folders are within the working directory:

```
purrr::iwalk(mylist, function(el, folder){
  purrr::walk(el,
              function(sub_el, folder){
                if(class(sub_el) == "list"){
                  purrr::iwalk(sub_el,
                               function(dat, dat_name, folder){
                                 write.csv(dat,
                                           # below line specifies file path of new file
                                           paste0(folder, "/", dat_name, ".csv"))
                               },
                               folder = folder)
                }
              },
              folder = folder)
})
```

Comment: AMAZING. I'll have to look more into purr.  What's the modification if the files aren't in the working directory (other than setting a new working directory)?

Comment: If the folders you want to write into aren't immediately within the working directory - you'd need to change the second argument to `write.csv` (in my case, the `paste0` line).

Comment: Tried that; say my path is in `outdir`.  `paste0(outdir, folder, "/", dat_name, ".csv")` creates the correct files PLUS an additional file, `1000.csv`.

Comment: hmm... if it's outside the working directory, you'll have to specify an absolute file path. If you already did that, be sure you're using `/` to separate `outdir` and `folder`? I wasn't able to reproduce that behavior when I wrote to an outside folder (it worked ok for me).

Comment: Yep, it' was the absolute path issue.  Fixed with: `paste0("~/", outdir, folder, "/", dat_name, ".csv")`. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain how you thought this through and what it means?